# Problem for a math formula in Weight Uncertainty in Neural Network

Tags: bayesian, mathematical-statistics, derivative, differential-equations

I am studying the paper ["Weight Uncertainty in Neural Networks"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.05424.pdf) by Blundell et al (2015, on arXiv), and there is a formula I don't get page 4, namely formula (3) in step 5:

[image]

I don't understand how they obtain formula (3). Moreover, it looks like with chainrule, I have $\partial f(w,\theta)/\partial\mu = \partial f(w,\theta)/\partial w$.  Could someone explain to me ? I am not very good with differentiation.

Comment: Welcome to CV! It seems that one has to read the paper in order to understand that formula - what is the relation between $f, \mu, \theta, w$? Please do not expect users to read a paper - give more information, and at least the title and authors of the paper - maybe you are lucky and someone knows the paper

Comment: I edited the original post so its more clear how the variables are linked. The paper title is Weight uncertainty in Neural network

Comment: Ah, $\theta = (\mu,\rho)$ - that was important! I edited a bit more, and added the proper reference to the paper. Also, it was important to know which of the formulas you meant, that got lost. You can't see the edits until they are reviewed by a moderator.

Comment: It might be useful to note that if you have a function $g(x,y)$, i.e. it explicitly depends on (x,y) and can be differentiated wrt to either, but you happen to know that y also depends on x (so in words, it's not possible to change x without changing y), then you can calculate a so-called total derivative of g wrt x given by 

$\frac{dg}{dx}=\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial g}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dx}$ (where the partial derivative wrt x is taken only against the explicit dependence of g on x)

Comment: Yes, and in the sense of @gazza89's comment, it was also important to know that $\boldsymbol{w}$ depends on $\mu$.

Comment: But i have a problem of dimensions. Lets assume that mu and rho are vectors of dimension n, how do i compute the  total derivative, do I use jacobian matrices ?